# How to get get Rto data using vehical no in android studio

Tags: government, india

How to get Rto data by vehical no in android studio any api available for get rto data ...

From where other apps are getting data.

Comment: What are the apps that are getting data??

Answer (score 1):

You can access the required data from the official website

[Ministry of Road Transport & Highways](https://vahan.nic.in/nrservices/faces/user/searchstatus.xhtml)
Government of India

[No Of Digitized Vehicles - 286,943,104](https://vahan.nic.in/nrservices/)

AFSIK Database access won't be authorized to everyone or publicly available due to security and confidentiality purposes.